# Does supercapacitor electrode need dielectric layer?

Tags: supercapacitor, dielectric, dielectric-breakdown

I am trying to build a super capacitor. I use Activated Carbon with Wood Glue, aluminium tin can as electrode, multi layers of tissue paper as separator, and table salt water as electrolyte.

No matter how many times I have tried in different ways, my supercapacitor is always conductive. I connect 3.7V battery, a Red LED (about 1.6V), and the supercapacitor in series. LED always lights up, doesn't dim at all. (I have taken out the RED led and powered the circuit with 1.5V battery, but nothing changes.)

I made a search about activated carbon, and it is said that they are electrically conductive.

Now I am thinking that electrode is conductive, activated carbon is conductive, salty water is conductive. Then why would this device build up charge at all? It is all conductive!

Should there be a dielectric layer between electrode and the activated carbon, so the current doesn't flow between positive and negative sides at all, and the ions of the salty water builds up in the pores of the activated carbon?

There is also bubbling together with hissing sound while the circuit is connected, but I guess I should be asking it separately.

Comment: Did someone tell you this would work?

Comment: There are 2 main properties conductive and insulative(=dielectric). Do not confuse the two. Water has a Dk of 80 but if conductive , the charge will decay

Comment: Actually it worked twice. Once it ran a DC motor for 16 minutes non-stop. But then it didn't work again. I am trying to understand the reasoning.

Comment: Did the  dielectric leak thru the paper separator ?  A motor no load is only 1% of start current

Comment: Somehow the conductive part mixed with the insulator and is boiling

Comment: This system can form a dielectric, as a thin AlO2 layer on the positive aluminium electrode (anode), formed by electrolysis. (aka "electrolytic" capacitor, the electrolytic reaction is also called "anodisation" as in anodised aluminium). But connect it incorrectly and you'll destroy that dielectric layer. Also I don't know if you can use table salt : anodisation normally uses weak sulphuric acid.